# How can the Sums of these two series be equal?

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading a thesis when I found:

> Gauss tried to find such a formula but he was only able to prove that
>   the function π(x) is well approximated by the logarithmic integral:

[image]

> Gauss’s estimate was motivated by the observation made by Euler about
>   the divergence of the series:

[image]

> In Euler’s terminology, S = log (log ∞), which was a consequence of the Euler’s product formula for the harmonic series:

[image]

So that:

[image]

***The question is how can the following be true?***

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Natural_logarithm) for $-\ln(1-x)$, valid for any $\lvert x\rvert <1$, is $-\ln(1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$.

Apply it to $\frac{1}{p}$, for any prime number $p$ (so that $0< \frac{1}{p}\leq \frac{1}{2}$):

$$-\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n p^n} = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{2p^2}+ \frac{1}{3p^3}+\ldots$$
You get the equality.

Comment: Many thanks, I have just missed that!!

Comment: You're welcome! (now, from your original post -- I assume the thesis you are reading does it carefully, but be weary of infinite series manipulations when they diverge -- as $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum_{p\text{ prime}} \frac{1}{p}$ do)

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the taylor series of $\ln(1-x)$ we can prove it like this $$(\ln(1-x))'=-\frac{1}{1-x}=-(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4\cdots$$
From that $$\int(\ln(1-x))'dx=\int-(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\cdots$$
plugging in $x=\frac1p$ you get $$\log(1-\frac1p)=\frac1p+\frac1{2p^2}+\cdots$$